# ¿porqué me duplica este WHILE?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

estoy trabajando una tabla donde sólo quiero mostrar los últimos cinco resultados, esto lo estoy haciendo con una condición en MySQL **LIMIT**. Pero al hacer el bucle while me duplica las **TR**, ¿alguien sabe dónde la estoy embarrando?

```
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#000000" style="color:#FFF;" align="center">Tus Reservas (Últimos 5 movimientos)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">Fecha</td>
            <td align="center">Observaciones</td>
            <td align="center">Estado</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <?php $sqlUno = "SELECT * FROM reservas ORDER BY id_reservas DESC LIMIT 5";
                $resultUno = mysqli_query($con, $sqlUno); 
                while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($resultUno)){ ?>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['fecha_res']?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['observaciones']?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['estado']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['fecha_res']?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['observaciones']?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['estado']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['fecha_res']?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['observaciones']?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['estado']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['fecha_res']?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['observaciones']?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['estado']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['fecha_res']?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['observaciones']?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['estado']?></td>
        </tr><?php
}
?>
    </table>
```

El resultado de este código debería de ser únicamente 5 celdas en la tabla con esta información, pero el resultado me da 10 celdas, duplicando cada valor que viene de la BBDD.

Agradeceré su ayuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu consulta ya están los 5 registros, en el while solo es mostrarlos. Te salen dobles porque por cada iteración lo haces "doble".

```
<?php 
    $sqlUno = "SELECT * FROM reservas ORDER BY id_reservas DESC LIMIT 5";
    $resultUno = mysqli_query($con, $sqlUno); 
    while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($resultUno)){ ?>
 <tr>
     <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['fecha_res']?></td>
     <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['observaciones']?></td>
     <td align="center"><?php echo $mostrar['estado']?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Con esto ya debería quedar.

Comment: También, para fines de **optimización**, en vez de `mysqli_fetch_array` puede usar **`mysqli_fetch_assoc`**, que es más específico. El primero trae dos veces los datos, como arreglo asociativo y numérico.

Comment: solo debes quitar 4 de los '<tr>' que tienes ya que el `while` te los repite en cada iteracción tal como lo escribio #Alexcode89